# How to find every 4-sheet covering of the wedge sum?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Based on this question [$4$-sheet covering of the wedge sum of two circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260578/4-sheet-covering-of-the-wedge-sum-of-two-circles) I know how to find *one* 4-sheet covering of the wedge sum, but how to find *every* 4-sheet covering of the wedge sum?

I really need help

Thanks a lot in advance